# colored columns with colored titles in beamer class

Tags: beamerposter, colorbox

I'm trying to create a 2-column poster using the beamer documentclass. Each column is to be split into several blocks and each of these blocks has its own title. The titles should have a background color different from the background color of the following text.

This is what I've tried:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackag{tcolorbox}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1em, text margin right=1em}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}    
\tcbox[title=TITLE1]%
{\begin{minipage}[t][0.48\textwidth][t]
{\dimexpr0.45\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-5pt\relax}
Some text1.
\end{minipage}}\hfill


\tcbox[title=TITLE2]%
{\begin{minipage}[t][0.49\textwidth][t]
{\dimexpr0.45\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-5pt\relax}
Some text2.
\end{minipage}}\hfill

\end{frame}        
\end{document}
```

Problem: The 2nd colorbox is in the same column as the 1st. It should be at the top of the right column. What am I doing wrong?

edit: my lame solution: using "\begin{multicols*}{2}" instead of "\begin{frame}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beamer` cannot know that you want two columns, unless you tell it. You can do so with `\begin{columns}...`

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1em, text margin right=1em}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 

\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \tcbox[title=TITLE1]%
        {\begin{minipage}[t][.5\textheight][t]
        {\dimexpr.8\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-5pt\relax}
        Some text1.
        \end{minipage}}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \tcbox[title=TITLE1]%
        {\begin{minipage}[t][.5\textheight][t]
        {\dimexpr.8\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-5pt\relax}
        Some text1.
        \end{minipage}}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}   
\end{frame}        
\end{document}
```

[image]